# How to fix cabal installation error

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-lens

I'm getting the following error when trying to install the contravariant library (which is needed for lens) with Cabal:

``src/Data/Functor/Contravariant.hs:96:1:
    StateVar-1.1.0.0:Data.StateVar can't be safely imported! The module itself isn't safe.''

I've not had any success googling solutions, and tried a few fixes (such as getting rid of all my Haskell packages (with ``rm -r ~/.ghc'') and starting again), but I'm not really clear on what's causing this error to occur. I'm using ghc 7.4.1 - could that be the problem?

Thanks,

Reuben

Comment: GHC 7.4.1 is pretty old. You will have a better luck with having recent version of GHC. Also you may want to try [Stack](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack) which is more easier.

Comment: Looks like you're being hit by interactions between an old GHC and the lack of [Safe Haskell](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/safe-haskell.html) annotations (in the library) that are redundant with newer GHC versions. Cf. https://github.com/ekmett/ersatz/issues/13 .

Comment: @duplode as your commment seems spot on, you should post it as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the correct answer from comments as community-wiki:

> Looks like you're being hit by interactions between an old GHC and the
>   lack of Safe Haskell annotations (in the library) that are redundant
>   with newer GHC versions. Cf. http://github.com/ekmett/ersatz/issues/13